# How to write automic operation in mongoDB integrated with python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x, pymongo

I created collection fee_details.

```
{
    "_id": "fee_details",
    "name": "Tution fees",
    "student_total": 30,
    "fee_notpaid": 29,
    "fee_paid_by": [{
    "stu_name": "jaya",
    "date": "10-09-2014"
    }]
}
```

I tried to enter `fee_paid_by` details using below query:

```
 db.fee_details.findAndModify({
    query: {
    "_id": "fee_details",
    "fee_notpaid": {
        $gt: 0
    }
    },
    update: {
    $inc: {
        "fee_notpaid": -1
    },
    $push: {
        "fee_paid_by": {
            "stu_name": "jaya",
            "date": "10-09-2014"
        }
    }
    }
})
```

It is executed on command line and adds `fee_paid_by` details to fee_details collection. But I tried execute below query integration with python

```
c = db.fee_details.find_and_modify({
    '$query': {
    "_id": "fee_details",
    "fee_notpaid": {
        '$gt': 0
    }
    },
    '$update': {
    '$inc': {
        "fee_notpaid": -1
    },
    '$push': {
        "fee_paid_by": {
            "stu_name": s_name,
            "fee": fee
        }
    }
    }
})
```

when executing this above code it gives an error `either must remove or update`

What is the correct way to enter `fee_paid_by` details into `fee_details` Collection??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[**`.find_and_modify`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify) takes a keyword arguments and keys name should not start by `$` sign.

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> db = client.test
>>> col = db.collection
>>> name = 'jaya'
>>> fee = 11
>>> query = {'_id': 'free_details', 'free_notpaid': {'$gt':0}}
>>> update = {'$inc': {'free_notpaid': -1}, '$push': {'free_paid_by': {'stu_name': name, 'fee': fee}}}
>>> col.find_and_modify(query=query, update=update)
```

---

The `find_and_modify` method is **DEPRECATED** since pymongo 3.0 you should use [find_one_and_delete()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_delete), [find_one_and_replace()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_replace), or [find_one_and_update()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) instead

```
>>> col.find_one_and_update(filter=query, update=update)
```